# Passing data from a label to another view controller

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, segue

what i have is when you select something is a uipickerview a label is than changed to the contents of the picker view. This works however I'm having trouble with taking the contents of the label in my pickerView.h and send it to set the contents of another label in my pickerDuration.h(secondViewController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay try this....

Have a `NSString` in ur `SecondViewController` and make sure u create a property of it (`strong`  if u are using IOS 5 ARC) Synthesize it

You must have an object of `SecondViewController` for navigation purpose. Use the same object to set the value like this

```
secondViewObj.myStr = label.text;
```

make sure u do that before navigating to the next view

**EDIT**

Okay Try this

After performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: your view controler will call
 assuming your new view controller has some propertys to set:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender


    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NextView"])   {
       SecondViewController *myVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        myVC.mystr=  label.text;
    }
```

Comment: what i did was in my secondViewController.h i added `@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *passdis;` than in my first view controller.m i added `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    pickerDuration *obj = [[pickerDuration alloc]init];
    obj.passdis = lblSelDistance.text;
}` now when i run the label will just go blank any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Create on object of SecondViewController in your currentViewController which has the label. Declare a string in SecondViewController.

Init secondViewController object in your currentViewController and set its NSString to label's text. Something like this

secondViewController.string = label.text;